# Java regex Pattern matches doesn't recognise "Escape +"

Tags: java, regex

I was trying the pattern `^\\+[0-9]+` to match `+852(2)78911`, but it seems that

`Pattern.matches("^\\+[0-9]+", s)`

is returning `false`. When I tried it in [regexr](http://www.regexr.com) it is working fine i.e. giving me a match. Am I not escaping this correctly in Java sense?

Comment: How come it works at regexpr if your pattern does not match parentheses? What result do you expect? I am sure you just need to use `Matcher#find()`.

Comment: It gives you this match: '+852' not the rest of the string

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex instead: `^\\+[0-9\\(\\)]+$`

Comment: You can find the formatting features here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  . There's no need to escape parenthesis inside a character class. Note too that when you use the `matches` method, anchors are implicit.